# How to import information from a text file into html or javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently working on creating a website that needs to access the text stored in a text file and parse it into a data structure. I would like to use a javascript function or an html tag to include or call the file so that I can parse it. However, I can't seem to find a good way to do it. Any suggestions?

I'm not sure how to be more specific, but perhaps some pseudocode might help. Current code would be along these lines:

```
mylist = new Array();

function myfunc()
{
    var str = [get information from website];
    mylist.push(str);
}
```

That is, if the website has the following text:

```
"<tag attr=str attr=str>text</tag>"
```

The newest (or last) element of mylist would be `"<tag attr=str attr=str>text</tag>".`

Thanks!

edit: Thanks for the quick responses. I was trying to steer away from jquery (actually, I'm implementing angular in the site), but I was trying to use a native javascript method as opposed to a library. Judging from the responses, there isn't one. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have to use AJAX to read data from web pages in Javascript.

Comment: Or use oldschool `iframe`

Comment: @b1- Don't use oldschool methods in programming, it's not as cool as driving oldschool cars, and it makes web's progress slower.
Iframe doesn't have any single advantage over Ajax

Comment: What have you tried so far? The comments above are gently pointing out that the "Ajax" functions of the jQuery javascript library are all ways of using Javascript's XmlHttpRequest to request a file and make it available in JS for parsing. The fact that you haven't at least found XHR so far makes me wonder how much research you've already done.

Comment: @pjmorse- Actually, I spent a couple of hours trying to do anything similar, and it was getting a little frustrating. Closest thing I found was embedding. I guess I just didn't know how to phrase it correctly in searching the web.

Comment: @NikolaNinkovic advantages: work without js; isolate content from main window, in case using html tags has normal render wo js. I prefer use KISS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [XHR Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest), aka the "AJAX" method.

[Here's an overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) as to how to start using it.

Here's an excerpt:

```
function makeRequest(url, callback) {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  //i'd omit this if I don't support older browsers
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
    try {
      httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {}
    }
  }
  if (!httpRequest) {
    alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
    return false;
  }
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
      callback(httpRequest.responseText);
    } else {
      alert('There was a problem with the request.');
    }
  }
  httpRequest.open('GET', url);
  httpRequest.send();
}
//using
makeRequest('path/to/your/file', function (contents) {
  myList.push(contents);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to load content from server in Your JS code.

Your `[get information from website];` should be replaced with function that fetch data.

Consider using jQuery for this [jQuery Docs on $.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

or use native JavaScript ajax [MDN docs on Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX)

Comment: You do notice that the OP never asked for jQuery, or even tagged it. Also, [w3schools is not a recommended reference site.](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: OP has tagged HTML and this have nothing to do with HTML, I'm just providing him some information and alternatives

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery $.get()

```
$.get('test.txt', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ for more details.